# node route passport current user id

Tags: node.js, cookies

the code I'm using gets current user id from cookies, but the user logged in does have another user id. I'm using passport authentication for the user. I want `user_id` to be the current passport user `user_id`.

current code uses cookie user id:

`routes.jes`

```
app.get('/portal', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
        var user_id = req.cookies ?
            req.cookies.user_id : undefined;

        Box.
        find({
            user_id: user_id
        }).
        sort('-updated_at').
        exec(function (err, boxes) {
            if (err) return next(err);

            res.render('portal', {
                user: req.user,
                boxes: boxes
            });
        });
    });
```

I've tried changing

```
var user_id = req.cookies ?
            req.cookies.user_id : undefined;
```

with e.g. `var user_id = req.user.user_id;`, and some other syntaxis but non work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using sessions ? ..If yes try req.session.user._id

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, solution was req.user.id instead of req.user.user_id hehe. If you put it as answer i'll mark yours as answer, because otherwise I have to wait 2 days before I can mark my own answer.

Comment: haha there you go :D ...console.log every obj when u cant access some property or something ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using sessions ? ..If yes try req.session.user._id

```
app.use(session({
    secret: 'MySuperSecret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000
}));
```

And when u log in with user store user obj in req.session, so you can access it anywhere you like.

```
req.session.user = user;
```

UPDATE:

Other solution that works when using passport:
change `var user_id = req.user.id;` to `var user_id = req.user.user_id;`